# a question about function arch_get_unmapped_area in memory management(linux)

Tags: c, linux, memory, operating-system, linux-kernel

in the book of http://www.ecsl.cs.sunysb.edu/elibrary/linux/mm/mm.pdf
page 202~203

```
if (addr) {
   addr = PAGE_ALIGN(addr);
   vma = find_vma(current->mm, addr);
   if (TASK_SIZE - len >= addr &&
   (!vma || addr + len <= vma->vm_start))
   return addr;
}
```

If addr is non-zero, we align it to a page boundary. We call the function
find vma() to see if the given address is contained in an existing VMA. If
it is not contained in any VMA and the end of the mapping is within the
process address space, we return the address.

**My question is:**
why we check addr + len <= vma->vm_start?
 how is it possible addr + len <= vma->vm_start? if an addr is found in a vma, then addr > vm_start, right? if len is positive (should be,right), so how could addr + len <= vma->vm_start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is made clear if you look at the remark in the source of find_vma:

/* Look up the first VMA which satisfies  addr < vm_end,  NULL if none. */

So, find_vma() might return a vma that doesn't actually map the address, hence the check.